# Presenting SKScene on a UIViewController not showing up

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sprite-kit, skscene

I have a ViewController that I created from storyboard.Upon a button tap event, I am trying to push a new Video Scene (which is a Custom SKScene that I made). The problem is that, this new SKScene gets added as i can hear the video playing. I just dont see it. The UIViewController's UI that I created from the Storyboard is all that I see.
Here's the code of presenting the scene

```
 VideoPlayScene * videoScene = [[VideoPlayScene alloc]initWithSize:skView.bounds.size fileName:@"myView.mp4"];
[skView presentScene:videoScene];
```

What do I do?

Comment: is the viewcontroller's view a SKView?

Comment: Any views that are added as the UIView's subviews will show up on top of your scene. You might have added a view which covers the whole of the view on which you are presenting the scene.

Comment: Alternatively, might not have called `SKView *skView = self.view;`